# Asynchronous operations in parallel CALLBACKS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, asynchronous

The following code is for Asynchronous operations in parallel.I have some doubts in the following code.
Let us take a small portion :
`book_instance_count: function(callback) {
        BookInstance.countDocuments({}, callback);`

MY questions:

1.Is `book_instance_count` the return value of function or a object ?

2.I am confused between the difference of two `callback` keyword in the code first at`function(callback)` and second at `BookInstance.countDocuments({}, callback);`.

`````
exports.index = function(req, res) {   
async.parallel({
        book_count: function(callback) {
            Book.countDocuments({}, callback); // Pass an empty object as match condition to find all documents of this collection
        },
        book_instance_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.countDocuments({}, callback);
        },
        book_instance_available_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.countDocuments({status:'Available'}, callback);
        },
        author_count: function(callback) {
            Author.countDocuments({}, callback);
        },
        genre_count: function(callback) {
            Genre.countDocuments({}, callback);
        }
    }, function(err, results) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library Home', error: err, data: results });
    });
};````
`````

Comment: Your functions take a callback (as a function) and pass further, to Book and BookInstance. book_instance_count doesn't return anything. What's the problem you're trying to solve? Or have you been just confused?

Comment: Thnaks ,well I was taking the MDN express.js tutorial (making a library web app), and the above is the code to render home page with no. of books and other details .I feel that we are defining a function with  `book_count: function(callback)` and  in the code `{Book.countDocuments({ }, callback);` we are implementing the function ``with an empty argument `{ } `  and a `callback`  but what the call back does here after the completion of function? am i right?

Comment: Yep, we're calling this function with 2 arguments, an empty object (probably some kind of a config) and the callback that is also a function, and we're taking it as an argument from the outer world.

Comment: You can't say what the callback does, it depends on what it is, only the caller of book_count function knows.

Comment: Also, you might want to check out https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#parallel to know more about the callback (it's not just a callback, async.parallel API page can tell what it is)

Comment: Your replies worked for me. Thanks.  :)

Comment: my pleasure :-)